# How do you properly set up Scala Spark libraryDependencies with the correct version of Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I'm new to Scala Spark and I'm trying to create an example project using Intellij. During Project creation I choose Scala and Sbt with Scala version  2.12 but When I tried adding spark-streaming version 2.3.2 if kept erroring out so I Google'd around and on Apache's website I found the sbt config shown below and I'm still getting the same error.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class SparkStreamingExample
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SparkStreamingExample
```

How can it be determined which version of Scala works with which version of Spark Dependencies?

```
name := "SparkStreamExample"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(

  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.3.2"
)
```

My Object class is very basic doesn't have much to it...

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext

object SparkStreamingExample extends App {
    println("SPARK Streaming Example")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the version of Scala that is supported by Spark in the [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/index.html).

As of this writing, the documentation says:

> Spark runs on Java 8+, Python 2.7+/3.4+ and R 3.1+. For the Scala API, Spark 2.3.2 uses Scala 2.11. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.11.x).

Notice that only Scala 2.11.x is supported.